# Creating a 64 bit shared library for aix powerpc

Tags: 64-bit, aix

I'm trying to make a shared library for AIX 7.1, but I keep getting those undefined reference errors, I'm trying to override them with various attempts but as you can see it isn't working. Can anybody help out with this? The gcc that I'm using is stand-alone but its built for the same machine and is hosted by the same machine. I'm using the ld that comes with binutils 2.22 which I also built for this machine. Thanks!

> bash-4.2$ gcc -shared  .libs/nvector_serial.o ../..//src/sundials/.libs/sundials_math.o  -lm  -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,-u -Wl,.strdod -Wl,-u -Wl,.__fd_select -Wl,-u -Wl,.printf -Wl,-u -Wl,.putchar -Wl,-u -Wl,.malloc -Wl,-u -Wl,.free -Wl,-soname -Wl,libsundials_nvecserial.so.0 -o .libs/libsundials_nvecserial.so.0.0.2
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x24): undefined reference to `.strtod'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xb0): undefined reference to`.__fd_select'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x118): undefined reference to `.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x148): undefined reference to`.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x168): undefined reference to `.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x17e): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against`N_VClone_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x18e): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against `N_VCloneEmpty_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x19e): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against`N_VDestroy_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1ae): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against `N_VSpace_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1be): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against`N_VGetArrayPointer_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1ce): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against `N_VSetArrayPointer_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1de): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against`N_VLinearSum_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1ee): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against `N_VConst_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1fe): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against`N_VProd_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x20e): relocation truncated to fit: R_TOC against `N_VDiv_Serial'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x21e): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x314): undefined reference to`.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x334): undefined reference to `.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x340): undefined reference to`.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x448): undefined reference to `.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x5f8): undefined reference to`.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x770): undefined reference to `.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x90c): undefined reference to`.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x9f8): undefined reference to `.printf'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xa20): undefined reference to`.putchar'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xa9c): undefined reference to `.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xacc): undefined reference to`.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xaec): undefined reference to `.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xe28): undefined reference to`.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xe48): undefined reference to `.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xe54): undefined reference to`.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0xf84): undefined reference to `.malloc'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x1074): undefined reference to`.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x10a4): undefined reference to `.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x10cc): undefined reference to`.free'
>   .libs/nvector_serial.o:./nvector_serial.c:(.pr+0x10e8): undefined reference to `.free'
>   ../..//src/sundials/.libs/sundials_math.o:./sundials_math.c:(.pr+0x24): undefined reference to`.strtod'
>   ../..//src/sundials/.libs/sundials_math.o:./sundials_math.c:(.pr+0xb0): undefined reference to `.__fd_select'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   bash-4.2$ file nvector_serial.o
>   nvector_serial.o: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
>   bash-4.2$

Comment: There are a lot more AIX heads on ittoolbox.com. Register and find the 'group' where this is the topic. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just import your libc symbols from libc rather all the stuff you are trying to do.  libc.a has shared objects in it so the result will use it as a dependency.  i.e. just put -lc.

That might not be all of your issues but that will clear up a lot of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies guys

I solved some of the "truncated to fit errors" by recompiling with the 64 bit instruction set as an option -mpowerpc64  i think it was, I don't know what the problem was exactly but it may have been that I somehow got gcc to compile for a 64 bit address space (-maix64 but no -mpowerpc64) but using only a 32 bit instruction set which is weird because -maix64 should imply -mpowerpc64 I believe. I may also have used -mminimal-toc but I still doubt that the TOC entries were overflowing

The rest of the errors(undefined references): I don't remember the exact reason why they were arising because I had tried so many ways to tell ld to ignore unresolved symbols but it was of no use.

I ended up using the XLC compiler for the linking stage and that solved the rest of the errors.